# TableView not refreshing after JSON Post using RestKit mapping

Tags: uitableview, rest, core-data, post, restkit

I am using RestKit to map JSON responses into CoreData. I have a tableview with UITextFields and a "Save" Button, which is supposed to POST the data to the server and save it. The server database is changed correctly, however the tableView reloads with the old data. Only if I go back and then into the view again the correct data is loaded.

I've spent hours and hours searching for a solution, but nothing I tried worked. If I put [self loadData] after the line with the POST, the app crashes, probably because the POST is not yet finished and there is a conflict. If I put [self.tableview reloadData] in that line it does not work either.

Here is my Code. I am using an NSManagedObject to save the data but sending a newly created NSObject (CommunityOtherProfile) back to the server.

This is my mapping:

```
    // CommunityProfile Object
RKManagedObjectMapping *profileMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CommunityProfile class] inManagedObjectStore:objectStore];
profileMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"uid";

[profileMapping mapKeyPath:@"uid" toAttribute:@"uid"];
[profileMapping mapKeyPath:@"nickname" toAttribute:@"nickname"];
[profileMapping mapKeyPath:@"hometown" toAttribute:@"hometown"];
[profileMapping mapKeyPath:@"male" toAttribute:@"male"];
[profileMapping mapKeyPath:@"age" toAttribute:@"age"];
[profileMapping mapKeyPath:@"description" toAttribute:@"profileDescription"];


[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:profileMapping forKeyPath:@"communityProfile"];

mappingForSerialization = [profileMapping inverseMapping];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] setSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:mappingForSerialization 
                                                                forClass:[CommunityProfile class]];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].router routeClass:[CommunityProfile class] toResourcePath:@"/community/profile/getMyProfile/" forMethod:RKRequestMethodGET];
//[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].router routeClass:[CommunityProfile class] toResourcePath:@"/community/profile/postMyProfile/" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];


// CommunityOtherProfile Object
RKObjectMapping *profileMapping2 = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CommunityOtherProfile class]];

[profileMapping2 mapKeyPath:@"uid" toAttribute:@"uid"];
[profileMapping2 mapKeyPath:@"nickname" toAttribute:@"nickname"];
[profileMapping2 mapKeyPath:@"hometown" toAttribute:@"hometown"];
[profileMapping2 mapKeyPath:@"male" toAttribute:@"male"];
[profileMapping2 mapKeyPath:@"age" toAttribute:@"age"];
[profileMapping2 mapKeyPath:@"description" toAttribute:@"profileDescription"];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:profileMapping2 forKeyPath:@""];

mappingForSerialization = [profileMapping2 inverseMapping];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] setSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:mappingForSerialization 
                                                                forClass:[CommunityOtherProfile class]];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].router routeClass:[CommunityOtherProfile class] toResourcePath:@"/community/profile/postMyProfile/" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];
```

This is where the POST happens:

```
- (void) save_clicked:(id)sender {

CommunityOtherProfile * newProfile = [[CommunityOtherProfile alloc] init];
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber * ageNumber = [f numberFromString:age.text];

NSString *tempDescription = @"Platzhalter (noch nicht implementiert!)";

newProfile.male = isMale;
newProfile.profileDescription = tempDescription;
newProfile.nickname = nickname.text;
newProfile.hometown = hometown.text;
newProfile.age = ageNumber;


// post Object
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:newProfile usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader){
    loader.targetObject = nil;
    loader.delegate = profileDataLoader;
}];
// I have tried to insert reloadData here }
```

other important methods in the same TableViewController class:

```
- (void) refreshView: (id) sender{

NSFetchRequest *request = [CommunityProfile fetchRequest];
prof = [[CommunityProfile objectsWithFetchRequest:request] objectAtIndex:0];    

    self.uid = prof.uid;
    self.nickname.text = prof.nickname;
    self.age.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [prof.age intValue]];
    self.hometown.text = prof.hometown;

     //self.description.text = prof.description;

    if(prof.male == [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]) {
        [self clickMale:self.male];
    }
    else if(prof.male == [NSNumber numberWithInt:0]) {
        [self clickFemale:self.female];
    } }
- (void) loadData{
profileDataLoader = [[CommunityProfileDataLoader alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
[profileDataLoader loadData];
```

And finally, my dataLoader class:

```
    //
//  CommunityProfileDataLoader.m
//

#import "CommunityProfileDataLoader.h"
#import "CommunityProfile.h"

@interface AbstractDataLoader()
@property CommunityEditProfileViewController *view;
@end


@implementation CommunityProfileDataLoader

@synthesize responseCode = _responseCode;
@synthesize view;

- (void) loadData{
    [super loadData];
    HCLog(DEBUG_MODE,@"Loading Profile Data");
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/community/profile/getMyProfile/" delegate:self];
}


- (void) triggerDelegate{
    HCLog(DEBUG_MODE,@"CommunityProfileDataLoader Triggering Delegate for %@", [super delegate]);
    [[super delegate] refreshView:self];
} /*...*/
```

I would be really happy if you guys could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Your table is running of a core data backed class CommunityProfile, but when you send the POST request, you only add your newly created profile to an in memory class CommunityOtherProfile. When you try to reloadData in save_clicked: nothing will have changed until the request has finished. When you come back to the view some time later, the request will have returned and your new object will be in core data and therefore the table view.

I wouldn't recommend manually saving it because it looks like your web service will return the uid and you will create a duplicate. (Hint: If you do decide to do this, set the targetObject of your objectloader to target the manually created object!)

I would suggest you reload the table when the web service has returned:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:newProfile usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader){
    loader.onDidLoadObject = ^(id obj) {
        [self refreshView: nil];
    };
}];
```